# Hide column header without changing positions of the other headers in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 columns. I want to hide the first column header (but keep the column body intact). My code is given below:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
th:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

This hides the first header all right, but causes the other headers to shift to the left, to fill up the space left by the missing header. How can I make them stay in the same place and not shift to the left? Please help!

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pahovavL/)

Comment: instead of **display:none;** use **opacity:0;**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `display:none` a whole `<th>` gets removed, and all of the other elements have to fill the space. What you need to do is ensure that the `<th>` element stays there, to fill the empty space. Use this:

```
th:first-child {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

or

```
th:first-child {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `visibility: hidden;`:

```
th:first-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The element will be hidden but it will allocate the space on the page.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pahovavL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

When you set a display to 'none', the whole element disappears, with that also the place that it's taking, you can avoid that by setting the opacity to 0:

```css
th:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```